# How to prepend a list Item in react correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have trouble to prepend a dynamically generated list item correctly

to show what i mean i setup this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodingBob/dx5o9sqn/4/)

1. add new item (type in 1)
2. add new value (type in a)
3. add new item (type in 2)

you will see that the value stays on top and is now inside item 2.

how do i fix this behavior so that the second added item has empty value and the first item keeps his value?

```
  class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: []
    }
  }

  addItem = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        items: [e.target.value, ...this.state.items]
    })
  }



  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <p>Add new Item</p>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.addItem}></input>
        <ul>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <h4>{item}</h4>
            <p>add New Value</p>
            <input type="text"></input>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            ...
```

The `key` prop is used by React as a reference to each item in a list, so it should be unique (and stable) for each item. Your `item` doesn't have an `id` property, it's just a string value from the input, so `item.id` is undefined. You could use `item` itself (the input value) as the key, as long as you don't expect any duplicate item names.

To make this more robust, you can store your items as objects with `value` and `id` properties, and generate a unique ID for each item as it's created. This is one simple way of doing that:

```
class TodoApp extends Component {

  state = {
    items: []
  }

  lastID = 0;

  addItem = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      items: [{ value: e.target.value, id: this.lastID++}, ...this.state.items]
    })
  }

  render() {
    ...
    {this.state.items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>
      <h4>{item.value}</h4>
        ...
  }
}
```

Note that we're mutating `lastID`, but in this case that's OK since it's a class property and not stored in `state` (it won't cause a re-render when it changes).